Why is changing the OS Catalina System disk's role to Data not working?
I am trying to change the role of my OS Catalina System disk to Data to prevent it from mounting automatically on startup.
I tried (as suggested here):
diskutil apfs changeVolumeRole /dev/disk1s5 Data

but got this error message:
Data is not a valid set of role flags to modify

I have also tried changing the fstab file to add the volume's UUID as noauto using sudo vifs.
Either or both don't seem to work. I'm using Catalina 10.15.7.

I have no idea whether this is relevant or not,  but in the answer that you reference the last parameter is "D" and not "Data".

You're trying to prevent the OS volume from mounting when it starts up? Doesn't it need to be mounted a bit?

I tried 'D' because the mentioned post only used 'D'. I also tried 'Data' with no luck. I don't want it to mount for a reason that will take up time and space to explain.
